# Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(X, M)$, and let $\mu^*$ be the outermeasure induced by $\mu$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(X, M)$, and let $\mu^*$ be the outermeasure induced by $\mu$. Suppose that $E \subset X$ satisfies $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(X)$ (but not that $E \in M$).

a.) If $A,B \in M$ and $ A \cap E = B \cap E$, then $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$. 
b.) Let $M_E = \{A \cap E : A \in M \}$ , and define the function $v$ on $M_E$ defined by $v(A \cap E)= \mu(A)$ (which makes sense by (a)). Then $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $v$ is a measure on $M_E$.

I am not sure how to start either of these problems. $E \notin M$ is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

The key point in a) is that $\mu^*(E)=\mu(X)$. So $\mu^*(E^c)=0$. Then 
$$
\mu^*(A)\leq\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^c)
\leq\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(E^c)=\mu^*(A\cap E)=\mu^*(B\cap E)\leq\mu(B). 
$$
As the roles of $A$ and $B$ can be reversed, you get $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.

For b): that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-\algebra follows from the fact that $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. You have $E=X\cap E\in M_E$. And $(A\cap E)\cap(B\cap E)=(A\cap B)\cap E$, so $M_E$ contains finite intersections. Similarly, $$\bigcup_n(A_n\cap E)=\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right)\cap E.$$ To check that $v$ is a measure, if $\{A_n\cap E\}$ are disjoint, then 
$$
v\left(\bigcup_nA_n\cap E\right)=v\left(E\cap\bigcup_n A_n\right)=\mu\left(\bigcup_nA_n\right)=\sum_n\mu(A_n)=\sum_nv(A_n\cap E). 
$$

Comment: For part b) why is $E = X \cap E \in M_E$? We do not know that $X$ is in $M$ right?

Comment: Of course it is, unless you are using definitons that are far from the usual. If you give me a measurable space $X$ with $\sigma$-algebra $M$, the assumption is that $X\in M$.

Comment: Then I am not sure how $E \subset X$ but $E \notin M$?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you think $M$ is?

Comment: $M$ is a $\sigma$ algebra. But $X$ is a set with $M \subset P(X)$.

Comment: Yes, and what's the definition of $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Okay so I went back to the definition and I see that $X \in M$. So just to make sure I am on the right track. Since $M$ is an $\sigma$ algebra and $E \subset X$ then $E$ must be in $M$. Right?

Comment: No! The $\sigma$-algebra $M$ consists of *some* subsets of $X$. And you assumed in your question that $E\not\in M$.

Comment: Okay I think I am beginning to understand. Thank you. I need to think of it all as subsets not elements.

Comment: Keep asking if you need to. You would probably benefit from reading a bit about $\sigma$-algebras and working a few examples on your own.